# Jquery : Replace the content of span inside the table column

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
    <table id="addressbook" >
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Company</th>
                <th>Documentation Address</th>
                <th>Type</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

         <tbody>
             <tr id="table-row_1">
                <td>Gigi World</td>
                <td>Cresent Road
                </td>
                <td  class="type-column"><span class="company-type">Shipper</span><br>
                    <span class="update-link"> <a data-code="11301181" id="Shipper" data-toggle="modal" role="button" class="rate update-anchor" href="#update-addresstype">Update</a>
                </span> <span id="delete-link" class="pull-right delete-link"> <a href="#" class="view-all">Delete</a></span>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>    
    </table>
```

table can have multiple row of same type.

```
  $(".update-link").click(function () {

   var elem = $(this).closest('tr');
});
```

after some manipulation  , i want to select the `third td (class name ="type-column")`of this perticular `tr` and want to replace the content of `first span (class name ="company-type")` with my own value lets say (eg, Hello World)

I tried

```
   elem.find("td:eq(2)").text("Hello World");
```

but its not working. help me!!

EDIT:
updated [jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/V85Vx/29/)

Comment: Is the missing round bracket in the `eq(2` only a typo in your code example or is it actually in your production code?

Answer (score 3):

You never searched for the `span`:

```
elem.find("td:eq(2)").find("span.company-type").text("Hello World");
```

Answer (score 0):

You had a few typos in your code.  Check this update: http://jsfiddle.net/V85Vx/29/

```
 $(".update-link").click(function () {
     alert("update clicked")
       var elem = $(this).closest('tr');
         elem.find("td:eq(1)").text("Hello World");
    });
```

Comment: i want to replace the content of third column not the second column

Comment: third column has got 3 spans .. i want to replace the content of first span

Comment: ok, I just went by your fiddle.  Try this for the first span in the third column: `elem.find("td:eq(2) span:eq(0)").text("Hello World");`