# Replace content of a column in html table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatable

I have a table with 3 columns and each of them have radio buttons (varying in number) based on the selected radio button the radio buttons for next column is shown.
I started coding this manually with jQuery and it started getting messy.
[image]
[image]
Ex: if i chose Mathematics It will show 5 categories, so here we need 3 additional rows. If i choose puzzles say there is only 3 categories so we have to remove 2 rows.

A small snippet from my code

```
var rows=$j('#gradeTable tr').length-1;
            var count=0;
            if(isParent==='true'){
                //If its a parent we are not rendering on table.But for child we have to 
            }
            else{
                for(var i=0;i<rows;i++){
                    count++;
                    var sel='#gradeTable tr:nth-child('+(i+2)+') td:nth-child(2)';
                    $j(sel).replaceWith(tds[i]);

                }
                console.log(data.length+'=================c'+count);
                if(count<data.length){
                    html='';
                    for(var i=count;i<data.length;i++){
                        html+='<tr><td></td>'+tds[count]+'<td></td><td></td></tr>'
                    }
                    $j("#gradeTable").append(html);
                }
            }
```

**tds[] is an array of data to be rendered to second column.**

> Am i overengineering or is there a simpler way to do this. Can i use
>   jQuery Datatable for this ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jquery : Replace the content of span inside the table column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20200349/jquery-replace-the-content-of-span-inside-the-table-column)

Comment: sorry @pennstatephil my requirement is different say i have 10 rows i want to replace column 2 for all 10 rows. Not just replace some SPAN insdie a particular column. The number of rows is dynamic it changes with each selection.

Comment: use `nth-child` for each `<tr>` edit: that's what you're doing. so... tell us what's wrong/not working?

Comment: well if you have read the code i have written above that is what I'm doing, the problem is its started getting too much complicated keeping track of total # of rows when a new value is selected if it have more rows than total# increase the rows, if # of rows of second column is less remove some rows from existing table etc.... is there a simpler way to do this ,for ex say using Datatable or similar (have not usedthese before).

Comment: I have read your code. Your question is confusing, sorry. Maybe if you were able to provide a demo at jsfiddle or some other code site it would be clearer.

Comment: @pennstatephil Sorry for the confusions,I have edited my question. It uses couple of rest services and some more conditions are there to avoid complexity i posted a snippet from the whole code, hence i doubt if  i can post any working thing to fiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used jQuery Data Table and used 3 arrays to store grade, subject and category. And created the dataset dynamically and provided to DataTable. This is far less complex than what I was trying to do.